# Strange error with user defined array creation function `cast`: Does not work when casting to class itself

Tags: matlab

Consider the following test class with user defined `cast`operator

```
classdef xxtest
properties (GetAccess=public, SetAccess=private)
    x
end

methods (Static)
    function A = cast( varargin )
        if nargin ~= 1
            err_
        end
        if isa(varargin{1}, 'xxtest')
            A = varargin{1};
        else
            A = xxtest;
            A.x = varargin{1};
        end
    end
end

methods 
    function obj = xxtest
        obj.x = 0;
    end
end
end
```

When casting from double everything works as expected

```
>> xx = cast( 1, 'xxtest' )

xx = 

   xxtest with properties:

   x: 0
```

But now when I try to cast the variable `xx` (which is already of the type 'xxtype') an error is generated.

```
>> cast( xx, 'xxtest' )
Error using cast
Unsupported data type for conversion: 'xxtest'.
```

This is very odd and makes no sense to me (for class `double` this casting to itself works as expected). Why is this and is there any way to avoid this problem by implementing the class `xxtest`differently?

I am using MATLAB 2014b.

I know that I could guard all calls to `cast` with `if ~strcmp(class(A),'xxtest')` but I want to avoid this "code pollution".